# Fatal error: require_once login Magento

Tags: magento, fatal-error, require-once, multiple-languages

I'm setting up a store with two languages. When I go to login in the default English everything is fine but if I try to login Spanish get the following error:

```
Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\htdocs\app\code\local;C:\xampp\htdocs\app\code\community;C:\xampp\htdocs\app\code\core;C:\xampp\htdocs\lib;.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\app\code\local\MageWorkshop\DetailedReview\controllers\Customer\AccountController.php on line 28
```

Here's line 28:

```
require_once 'app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php';
```

The "missing" not found file is there!

Does anyone know how I can fix this? Or is this like a major problem that requires a professional?

The Spanish people will not be able to login.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the directory-path is not **absolute** then it is assumed to be **relative** to the ServerRoot location.

Just specify the server root location, your script/module seems to be wrong installed.

```
define('MAGENTO_LOCATION', '/var/www/vhosts/mysite');

require_once MAGENTO_LOCATION . '/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php';
```

Comment: I'm very sure my module is install correctly. Everything works about it except for the login for the second language.It looks like it's pointing in the right place. My Magento index is here: C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php my second language index is here: C:\xampp\htdocs\es\index.php My store is working perfectly, no errors anywhere in system.logs, exception.logs, or php.logs  I get a start-up error in my MySQL.logs but I don't try to ever restart it. :)

Comment: I've tried removing detailed review like this because it didn't seem to be needed on the account login but it still didn't correct the error:   <customer_account_login>
<reference name="head" as="head">
   <action method="unsetChild"><name>detailedreview_header_include_js</name></action>
   <action method="unsetChild"><name>detailedreview_header_css</name></action>  
   <action method="unsetChild"><name>detailedreview_header_timezone</name></action>   
   <action method="unsetChild"><name>recently_reviews</name></action>
</reference>   
</customer_account_login>

Comment: OK, this is Windows related (Backslash vs. Forward slash). You should run Magento on Linux. It's not recommended, to use XAMPP as a production server.

Comment: That's what I'm planning on. So you think after I move my site live it will be ok?

Comment: Yes, I guarantee it. I've had weird problems with XAMPP as a test environment in the past. See http://superuser.com/questions/327820/what-is-the-difference-between-forward-slashes-and-backslashes-in-paths